# Problem in plotCountDepth R function. How to solve it?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, rna-seq

I'm dealing with a dataframe that i called GBM that contains single-cell measurements. So i'm relying to SCnorm package to deal with the normalization process and to have a previous check of my data. I'm using  ([plotCountDepth function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/SCnorm/man/plotCountDepth.html))

This is my pipeline :

```
sce <- SingleCellExperiment::SingleCellExperiment(assays = list('counts' = GBM))
                                                  
                                                  
                                                  sce <- plotCountDepth(Data = sce,
                                                                        
                                                                                Conditions = Label,
                                                                        
                                                                                   FilterCellProportion = .1,
                                                                        
                                                                                                     NCores = 3)
```

I do not really understand why I continue to have this error returned

**Error in colSums(Data[, which(Conditions == Levels[x])]) :
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions**

even if I'm applying the same criteria I find in [BioConductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/SCnorm/inst/doc/SCnorm.pdf)

For you to have major information Label is a vector of the same dimension  of GBM that is a matrix G x S, containing a series of labels to distinguish each cell group.

Thank you in advance

PS : GBM is a matrix which columns are named by the various  cell names  while the rows are of course the genes

Answer (score 0):

As the vignette stated:

> Data: can be a matrix of single-cell expression with cells where rows
> are genes and columns are samples. Gene names should not be a column
> in this matrix, but should be assigned to rownames(Data).

Below I provide a minimum working example and I suggest you check whether you specified the rownames correctly:

```
library(SingleCellExperiment)
library(SCnorm)
GBM = matrix(rpois(10000,20),ncol=50)
rownames(GBM) = paste0("Gene",1:200)
colnames(GBM) = paste0("Sample",1:50)
Label=rep(c("X","Y"),each=25)
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(assays = list('counts' = GBM))
```

This function works but it is not very well written because it prints out the ggplot object but there's no way of storing it:

```
plt <- plotCountDepth(Data = sce,Conditions = Label,
FilterCellProportion = .1,NCores = 3)
```